# Repeater.js using multiple nested form. Add button adds fields to all

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the nested form created using repeater.js 
https://github.com/DubFriend/jquery.repeater

But when I click the add button it adds a new field to every item.

I tried adding div with repeater based on https://github.com/DubFriend/jquery.repeater/issues/90 but I think that is the case with single repeater but this is nested

Please help. I could n't find a method to fix it.

[image]

```
<!-- outer repeater -->
<form class="repeater">
   <div class="repeater">
      <div data-repeater-list="outer-list-1">
         <div data-repeater-item>
            <input type="text" name="text-input" value="A"/>
            <input data-repeater-delete type="button" value="Delete"/>
            <!-- innner repeater -->
            <div class="inner-repeater">
               <div data-repeater-list="inner-list-1">
                  <div data-repeater-item>
                     <input type="text" name="inner-text-input" value="B"/>
                     <input data-repeater-delete type="button" value="Delete"/>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <input data-repeater-create type="button" value="Add"/>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <input data-repeater-create type="button" value="Add"/>
   </div>
   <div class="repeater">
      <div data-repeater-list="outer-list-2">
         <div data-repeater-item>
            <input type="text" name="text-input" value="A"/>
            <input data-repeater-delete type="button" value="Delete"/>
            <!-- innner repeater -->
            <div class="inner-repeater">
               <div data-repeater-list="inner-list-2">
                  <div data-repeater-item>
                     <input type="text" name="inner-text-input" value="B"/>
                     <input data-repeater-delete type="button" value="Delete"/>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <input data-repeater-create type="button" value="Add"/>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <input data-repeater-create type="button" value="Add"/>
   </div>
</form>
<script src="path/to/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="path/to/jquery.repeater/jquery.repeater.js"></script>
<script>
   $(document).ready(function () {
       $('.repeater').repeater({
           // (Required if there is a nested repeater)
           // Specify the configuration of the nested repeaters.
           // Nested configuration follows the same format as the base configuration,
           // supporting options "defaultValues", "show", "hide", etc.
           // Nested repeaters additionally require a "selector" field.
           repeaters: [{
               // (Required)
               // Specify the jQuery selector for this nested repeater
               selector: '.inner-repeater'
           }]
       });
   });
</script>
```

Comment: When I try the code it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jkzm8.jpg). What CSS are you using?

Comment: I have the same problem but not getting any solution :(

Comment: @FarrukhSarmad move `<input data-repeater-create type="button" value="Add"/>` outside the repeateing div